# Android Studio generate core dump CMake

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb, coredump, ndk-gdb

I'm trying to generate a core dump for my android studio application. It's written in Java, however I'm trying to generate a coredump due to the fact that the crashes are happening in my native library.

I'm using cmake to configure the native library, not Android.mk.

So when i try to run `ndk-gdb` i get:

```
*** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
ERROR: Failed to retrieve application ABI from Android.mk.
```

How do i go about getting a core dump when i'm using CMake in my application? How do I go about running `gdb` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ndk-gdb doesn't work with CMake. Your best bet will be to use Android Studio's C++ debugging features.